# Regex for android calculator

Tags: android, regex

I am writing a regex for an android calculator. The "+/-*" are okay for non decimal values but the problem lies in the ".". How do i check for the "." ?

Here is my regex :

```
"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"
```

This is my method for calculations:

```
 private double calc(String resultString) {
        String[] result = resultString.split("(?<=[^\\\\d.])(?=\\\\d)|(?<=\\\\d)(?=[^\\\\d.])");
        String op = null;
        double res = 0;

        for (String s : result) {
            if (s.equals("+") || s.equals("-") || s.equals("*") || s.equals("/") ) {
                op = s;
            }
            else if(s.equals(".")){




            }




            else {
                if (op == null) {
                    res = Double.parseDouble(s);
                } else {
                    if (op.equals("+")) {
                        res = res + Double.parseDouble(s);
                    } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                        res = res - Double.parseDouble(s);
                    } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                        res *= Double.parseDouble(s);
                    } else if (op.equals("/")) {
                        res /= Double.parseDouble(s);
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        return res;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the `.` from the `\D` shorthand with a negated character class `[^\d.]` that will match any char but a digit and a literal `.` (note the `.` does not have to be escaped in the character class to be parsed as a literal dot):

```
"(?<=[^\\d.])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[^\\d.])"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M6MUtV/1)

And an [online demo](https://ideone.com/nQwam7) (in Java):

```
String resultString = "1-1+0.4/2+0.5*4";
String[] result = resultString.split("(?<=[^\\d.])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[^\\d.])");
String op = null;
double res = 0;

for (String s : result) {
    if (s.equals("+") || s.equals("-") || s.equals("*") || s.equals("/") ) {
        op = s;
    }
    else {
        if (op == null) {
            res = Double.parseDouble(s);
        } else {
            if (op.equals("+")) {
                res = res + Double.parseDouble(s);
            } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                res = res - Double.parseDouble(s);
            } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                 res *= Double.parseDouble(s);
            } else if (op.equals("/")) {
                res /= Double.parseDouble(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(res); // => 2.8 (= 1-1+0.4/2+0.5*4)
```

Comment: This fails to parse the double.

Comment: Please provide your code and sample input/expected output.

Comment: I added the calculation method above

Comment: You used a wrong regex. I wrote to use `"(?<=[^\\d.])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[^\\d.])"` and it works.

Comment: A calculation of 6.6*6 should output 39.6 but its outputting 39.59999994. Why so and how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, because you are converting string numbers to double. Round the values if you need just specific number of fractional digits. Something like `String.format("%.1f", res)` can also be used to show the result.